# views-exposed-form drill down

Tags: 7

I need to show taxonomy groups in an exposed form to the left of a map. I am able to do that no problem; however, I have a further requirement to drill down into each taxonomy group and expose the individual markers associated with each taxonomy term.

Taxonomy term group
    - marker 1
    - marker 2
Taxonomy term group 2
    - marker 3
    - marker 4

Is there a way to make this happen?